# Высказывание из сочинения

Tags: смысл, анализ-текста

Здравствуйте! Никак не могу перефразировать фразу А. В. Щербакова " Явление антонимии в языке обусловлено свойственным человеку восприятием действительности во всей противоречивой сложности"

Comment: Простите, а зачем её перефразировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А. В. Щербаков сказал: " Явление антонимии в языке обусловлено свойственным человеку восприятием действительности во всей противоречивой сложности". Это действительно так, правильное употребление антонимов в речи помогает раскрыть противоречивую сущность предметов, явлений, качеств.

А дальше - к тексту: В данном тексте в предл. №... мы видим антитезу на основе антонимов.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сказал, что наоборот. Явление антонимии в языке обусловлено свойственным человеку стремлением к упрощению. Хорошо или плохо? Тепло или холодно? Умный или дурак?